# How to log my entity errors detailed

Tags: entity-framework, logging, reflection

I want to store my entity classes' properties' values as extra if occurred any error. What is the best practises to do this ? I thought, getting values by reflection and write them to database is a good solution but then It creates another question. How can I reach all values including Collections'  values, in other words children objects' values. I have tried to reach by using reflection but I stucked,failed. If my solution is wrong, I am open to any suitable solutions, suggestions :)

For example :

```
public class Author : BaseEntity
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the author's name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the author's surname
    /// </summary>
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the author's birthdate
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the author's death of date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DeathDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating rating entity
    /// </summary>
    public virtual AuthorRating Rating { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating idenitifier of the author's nationality
    /// </summary>
    public int NationalityId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating the author's nationality
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Nation Nationality { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of votes
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorVote> HavingVotes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of quotes which he/she said
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Quote> OwnQuotes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of favourited rows by user
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<UserFavouriteAuthor> Favouriteds { get; set; }

}
```

For example, How can I reach Author.Qutes.QuoteVotes class and their values and their childrens recursively by using reflection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle a DbEntityValidationException, surround your DbContext related code in a `try catch` block and use this for your exception

```
public void AppendValidationErrors(Exception e)
{
    DbEntityValidationException ex = e is DbEntityValidationException ?
        e as DbEntityValidationException : null ;

    if (ex == null) { log.Info(e); return; }

    foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        log.Info(string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));

        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            log.Info(string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

To get the property values, you can use EF's DbPropertyValues

```
    public static void PrintValues(DbPropertyValues values) 
    { 
        foreach (var propertyName in values.PropertyNames) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Property {0} has value {1}", 
                              propertyName, values[propertyName]); 
        } 
    }

   PrintValues(context.Entry(User).GetDatabaseValues());
```

Comment: It is not the problem. Simply,in addition, I  want to log the entity object with its properties. Such as, An error occurred while  performing any CRUD operations then I want to log related entity such as, User - UserName : "Test User", Surname : "Sur" , bla bla. I already did your solution but I want to do a little bit more for more detailed error logging.

Comment: Yeah, just thing.. It worked as I want. Good solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log your database's erroneous behavior, you can inhert from the Entity Framework's`IDbCommandInterceptor` and intercept the database's warnings and errors.

```
/// <summary>
/// The supported logging types
/// </summary>
public enum LogTarget { Log4net, Console, File };


public class DbCommandLogger : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
   #region Appender Definitions

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign a method to append an error
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="error">The error to append</param>
    private Action<string> appendError;

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign a method to append a warning
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="warning">The warning to append</param>
    private Action<string> appendWarning;

    #endregion


    #region Fields

    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("WarningsAndErrorsAppender");

    #endregion


    #region Construct and Setup

    public DbCommandLogger(LogTarget logTarget, string path = "db")
    {
        SetupAppenders(logTarget, path);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Setups appenders according to the specified log target. It can only be accessed via the constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logTarget">The log target</param>
    /// <param name="path">The file path. Leave empty if you don't want to specify a path</param>
    private void SetupAppenders(LogTarget logTarget, string path = "db")
    {
        switch (logTarget)
        {
            case LogTarget.Console:
                appendError = Console.Write;
                appendWarning = Console.Write;
                break;
            case LogTarget.File:
                appendError = File.CreateText(path + ".Errors.log").WriteLine;
                appendWarning = File.CreateText(path + ".Warning.log").WriteLine;
                break;
            case LogTarget.Log4net:
                appendWarning = x => log.Warn(x);
                appendError = x => log.Error(x);
                break;
            default:
                appendWarning = x => { };
                appendError = x => { };
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Queries

    public void NonQueryExecuting(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext);
    }   

    public void ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext);
    }

    #endregion


    #region Log Commands

    /// <summary>
    /// Log a warning for any command that is executed non-asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    private void LogIfNonAsync<TResult>(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (!interceptionContext.IsAsync)
        {
            appendWarning(String.Format("Non-async command used: {0}", command.CommandText));
         }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Log an error for any command that throws when executed
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="command">The command being executed.</param>
    /// <param name="interceptionContext">Contextual information associated with the call.</param>
    private void LogIfError<TResult>(
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
        {
            appendError(String.Format("Command {0} failed with exception {1}",
                 command.CommandText, interceptionContext.Exception));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Helpers

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public string GetCurrentMethod()
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);

        return sf.GetMethod().Name;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

You can then register the interceptor using a DbContext extension method

```
/// <summary>
/// Logs erroneous database behavior. Set the appender method via the log4net.config file located in the project's target folder
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The DbContext object that's being tracked</param>
public static void LogWarningsAndErrors(this DbContext context,LogTarget logTarget)
{
    string path = FolderExists("LogFiles") ? "LogFiles\\" + context.ToString() :context.ToString();

    DbInterception.Add(new DbCommandLogger(logTarget, path));
}
```

Finally, you can easily log the errors via your DbContext like this:

```
context.LogWarningsAndErros(LogTarget.Log4Net);
```

Comment: It is a good solution but I have a problem with it. DbContext throw s DbEntityValidationException before executing query, on SaveChanges(), so It becomes an obligatory that I must log in try catch blogs in the repositories. So solution doesn't benefit to me.